# Office network with Sound system

Tags: audio, sound-system

I am looking for recommendations for a sound system for our new office. It has to have at least 4 zones with at least an input from each zone and be able to run 10 "ceiling speakers". I want to control it with apps, Bluetooth, and network computers.

I will be doing all the low voltage in the new office, and I have never set up a sound system before so I want some recommendations. I would like a system that has an app so It can be controlled from anywhere in the office and I also want to be able to add wireless speakers if needed.

I will be running cat6 drops to the Data room so if the speakers need LAN connections I can dedicate those to them or I can use speaker wires. I just need a little guidance in the right direction, If I have to create a subnetwork for the Audio Receiver that would be not a problem at all.